# Oracle segment statistics query

Tags: sql, oracle

The following query outputs the total logical reads on tables for the last 7 days:

```
SELECT owner as schema, object_name AS table_name,
     sum(logical_reads_delta) AS total_logical_reads
FROM dba_hist_seg_stat a, dba_hist_seg_stat_obj b
WHERE     owner != 'SYS'
     and owner!= 'SYSTEM'
     AND a.obj# = b.obj#
     AND a.dataobj# = b.dataobj#
     AND object_type = 'TABLE'
GROUP BY owner, object_name
order by sum(logical_reads_delta) desc;
```

If it's not in the output, it doesn't have a logical read.

I'm actually looking for a way to join ALL the tables in the database (even ones without logical reads) with the above output. Outer join?

The result will hopefully be a list of recent activity on the database listing all of the tables with logical reads (and some with null values)

Ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I have misunderstood the question but would this query go some way to solving your problem?

I have linked your query to `DBA_TABLES` (with an outer join) so it can retrieve all the tables available in your DB listing those with logical reads first.

```
SELECT t.owner AS schema_name,
       t.table_name,
       q.total_logical_reads
  FROM dba_tables t
  LEFT JOIN
      (SELECT b.owner AS schema,
              b.object_name AS table_name,
              SUM (a.logical_reads_delta) AS total_logical_reads
         FROM dba_hist_seg_stat a
         JOIN dba_hist_seg_stat_obj b USING (obj#, dataobj#)
        WHERE b.owner NOT IN ('SYS', 'SYSTEM')
          AND b.object_type = 'TABLE'
        GROUP BY b.owner, b.object_name) q
   ON (t.owner = q.schema AND t.table_name = q.table_name)
ORDER BY q.total_logical_reads DESC NULLS LAST;
```

Hoe it helps...